# How can I make this tiny Python 2.7 complex number code snippet work the same with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, complex-numbers

check.py —

```
import sys

def main():
    h = 5
    for y in range(h):   
        fy = 2j * y / h - 1j
        print ( fy )    
        
main()
```

expected result —

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
$ python check.py
-1j
-0.6j
-0.2j
0.2j
0.6j
```

but —

```
$ python3  --version
Python 3.10.1
$ python3 check.py
-1j
-0.6j
-0.19999999999999996j
0.19999999999999996j
0.6000000000000001j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide after the subtraction:

```
def main():
    h = 5
    for y in range(h):   
        fy = (2j * y - h * 1j) / h
        print(fy)
```

Output:

```
-1j
-0.6j
-0.2j
0.2j
0.6j
```

Comment: What Python 2 change creates this difference ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's posible you can use round method for imag part, like this:

import sys

```
def main():
    h = 5
    for y in range(h):
        fy = 2j * y / h - 1j
        print(round(fy.imag, 2))


main()
```